# SQL Server : Create Procedure in DB without using [GO]

Tags: sql-server, node.js, procedure, node-mssql

I want to execute this (simplified) query using `node-mssql` that executes in SQL Server 2017 fine:

```
USE [Journal]
[GO]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EventDelete]
    @NotificationID INT
AS
    DELETE Notification
    WHERE NotificationID = @NotificationID
[GO]
```

`node-mssql` declares syntax error using `[GO]` and requires semicolon, therefore I try this:

```
USE [Journal];

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[EventDelete]
    @NotificationID INT
AS
    DELETE Notification
    WHERE NotificationID = @NotificationID;
```

Now we get error:

> CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

So let's try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Journal].[dbo].[EventDelete]
    @NotificationID INT
AS
    DELETE Notification
    WHERE NotificationID = @NotificationID;
```

Now we get

> RequestError: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Naturally without any DB declaration it attempts to attach to the master error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE permission denied in database 'master'.

Answer (score 0):

So writing the question really works at setting one's thoughts straight.

The reason is the stored procedure requires to be created in one batch, which [GO] signifies, with nothing else.

Execute `USE [Journal]` as one batch using the `.batch('USE [Journal]')` method and then the SQL to `CREATE PROCEDUCE` as a new `.batch(...)` execution, sequentially.

Unless there is another method within node-mssql which allows for multi-batch executions?

Comment: In most languages/environments, one can (and usually does) specify the database to use when establishing a connection. That is a good habit to develop for many reasons - this is just one.

Comment: Good point, the connection is set to Master; adding procedures to different DBs should one disconnect and reconnect?